# Spring Boot With Hibernate: Unknown column 'book0_.AuthorN' in 'field list'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I need some help with this spring Boot Application with Hibernate. I am trying to get data from the database and for some reason some reason, I keep getting this error message **Unknown column 'book0_.AuthorN' in 'field list'** I know that there is a column in the Book Table call **AuthorN**, but I keep getting the error message. It also does the Same thing for **ISBN in the Book Table.**

**Here is MySQL Script.**

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(
ProductID   INT          NOT NULL

PRIMARY KEY (ProductID)

) ENGINE = innoDB;

CREATE TABLE Author
(
AuthorNum   INT        NOT NULL

PRIMARY KEY (AuthorNum)

) ENGINE = innoDB;


CREATE TABLE Book
 (
BookNum   INT         NOT NULL,
AuthorN INT NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (BookNum),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (BookNum) REFERENCES Product (ProductID),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (AuthorN) REFERENCES Author(AuthorNum)

) ENGINE = innoDB;


CREATE TABLE Image
(
ImageNum   INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ProductImgID   INT         NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (ImageNum),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (ProductImgID) REFERENCES Product(ProductID)

) ENGINE = innoDB;
```

**Product.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Product")
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@NotNull(message = "Product id is required")
@Column(name = "ProductID")
public Long getProductID() {
    return productID;
}

public void setProductID(Long productID) {
    this.productID = productID;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
public List<Image> getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(List<Image> image) {
    this.image = image;
}

@NotNull(message = "Product name is required")
@Column(name = "ProductName")
public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

@NotNull(message = "Product description is required")
@Column(name = "Description")
public String getProductDisc() {
    return productDisc;
}

public void setProductDisc(String productDisc) {
    this.productDisc = productDisc;
}

@NotNull(message = "Product type is required")
@Column(name = "Type")
public String getProductType() {
    return productType;
}

public void setProductType(String productType) {
    this.productType = productType;
}

@Null
@Column(name = "Price")
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

@NotNull(message = "Product release date is required")
@Column(name = "ReleaseDate")
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
}
```

**The Book.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Book")
public class Book extends Product{

@NotNull(message = "Book number is required")
@Column(name = "BookNum")
public int getBookNum() {
    return bookNum;
}

public void setBookNum(int bookNum) {
    this.bookNum = bookNum;
}

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "AuthorN")
public Author getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(Author author) {
    this.author = author;
}

@NotNull(message = "Book ISBN is required")
@Column(name = "ISBN")
public String getBookISBN() {
    return bookISBN;
}

public void setBookISBN(String bookISBN) {
    this.bookISBN = bookISBN;
}
}
```

**Author.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Author")
public class Author {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@NotNull(message = "Author id is required")
@Column(name = "AuthorNum")
public int getAuthorNum() {
    return authorNum;
}

public void setAuthorNum(int authorNum) {
    this.authorNum = authorNum;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
public List<Book> getBooks() {
    return books;
}

public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
    this.books = books;
}

@NotNull(message = "Author name is required")
@Column(name = "AuthorName")
public String getAuthorName() {
    return authorName;
}

public void setAuthorName(String authorName) {
    this.authorName = authorName;
}

@Null
@Column(name = "AboutAuthor")
public String getAboutAuthor() {
    return aboutAuthor;
}

public void setAboutAuthor(String aboutAuthor) {
    this.aboutAuthor = aboutAuthor;
}
}
```

**BookRepository.class**

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {

}
```

**BookService.class**

```
@Service
public class BookService {

private BookRepository repository;

@Autowired
public BookService(BookRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

public List<Image> getImage() {
    List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Book> products = (List<Book>) repository.findAll();
    return new ArrayList<>();
}

}
```

**Debug SQL Query From Hibernate**

```
Hibernate: 
/* select
    generatedAlias0 
from
    Book as generatedAlias0 */ select
        book0_.ProductID as ProductI2_2_,
        book0_.ReleaseDate as ReleaseD3_2_,
        book0_.Price as Price4_2_,
        book0_.Description as Descript5_2_,
        book0_.ProductName as ProductN6_2_,
        book0_.Type as Type7_2_,
        book0_.AuthorN as AuthorN10_2_,
        book0_.ISBN as ISBN8_2_,
        book0_.BookNum as BookNum9_2_ 
    from
        Product book0_ 
    where
        book0_.DTYPE='Book'
```

**Why is Hibernate Selecting from the Product Table And not From the Book Table?
Is there a way how to solve this problem?**

Comment: Not clear what your problem exactly is. Where (by doing what) do you get the mentioned error message? The displayed query does not seem to fit to the displayed Book class (missing fields). BTW: Why there are no members in your entity classes?

Comment: Here is the error I am getting  **java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'book0_.AuthorN' in 'field list'** It said that In the Book.class or Table, that there is no **AuthorN**. It Even does the same thing for **ISBN in the Book.class and the Book Table**